# Alexander Whitney: Diagonal Approximation

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, category-theory, homological-algebra

Given topological spaces $X$ and $Y$.

Regard their singular complexes $S_*X$ and $S_*Y$
as well as the singular complex $S_*(X\times Y)$.

Choose a natural homotopy equivalence:
$$AW:S_*(X\times Y)\leftrightarrow S_*X\otimes S_*Y:EZ$$
Existence follows by acyclic models theorem!

In detail, they are homotopy inverses:
$$AW\circ EZ\simeq1\quad EZ\circ AW\simeq1$$
while both are natural in either space.

Consider the diagonal map:
$$\Delta:X\to X\times X:\quad \Delta x:=(x,x)$$

Combine it with an Alexander Whitney map:
$$AW\circ\Delta_*:S_*X\to S_*(X\times X)\to S_*X\otimes S_*X$$

> It is a diagonal approximation:
>   $$\sigma\in S_0X:\quad(AW\circ\Delta_*)\sigma=\sigma\otimes\sigma$$
>   How can I check this action?