# On the definition of cap product

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, tensor-products

I'd like to understand the definition of cap product, strictly realated with [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4129139/sign-in-definition-of-cap-product) previous question that I was not able to appreciate since I don't understand the costruction.

I'm going to cite my notes taken in class:

Take $C^{\bullet}(X) = \text{Hom}(C_\bullet(X),\mathbb{Z})$, then there is a natural evaluation map $$\langle,\rangle : C^{i}(X) \times C_{i}(X) \longmapsto \mathbb{Z}$$

I'd like to make this evaluation an homomorphism of complex in the following way: I can think to the cochain complex as a chain complex changing the degree $C_i := C^{-i}$ with differential $d_i = d^{-i}$. So we're thinking $\left\lbrace C^{i}(X) \right\rbrace_i$ as a chain complex with the the convention cited.

It easily follows that $\langle,\rangle$ induces $$\varepsilon_0 : (C^{\bullet}(X) \otimes C_{\bullet}(X))_0 \longmapsto \mathbb{Z}$$

Where I think to $\mathbb{Z}$ as the degree $0$ term of a complex with $0$ in all other degrees, and we define $\varepsilon_n = 0$ if $n\ne 0$.

**What I don't get :**

$1.$ If $\left(C^{\bullet}(X) \otimes C_{\bullet}(X)\right)_0 = \bigoplus\limits_{p+q = 0}C^{p}(X) \otimes C_q(X)$ shouldn't this complex be equal to $C^0(X) \otimes C_0(X)?$ I don't get why we have "all"(they should be non negative anyway) the degrees, is this related to thinking the cochain complex as a chain complex? I don't understand.

$2.$ In order to prove that $(\varepsilon_n)_n $ is a chain morphism, why should we take $f \in C^i(X)$ and $\alpha \in C_{i+1}(X)?$

Any help or reference about this process (which leads to define the cap product) would be appreciated.

Comment: For 1., remember the changing degree convention between chain and cochain complexes. It follows that $(C^\bullet(X)\otimes C_\bullet(X))_n=\bigoplus_{-p+q=n}C^p(X)\otimes C_q(X)$.

Comment: @Roland I'm afraid this is one of my problems

Comment: It is just one way to "collapse" a double complex (i.e., $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$-graded) to a single complex (called the total complex), similar to using total degree for multivariable polynomials.