# Why do we use Koszul-sign rule

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, tensor-products

Trying to understand the essence of cap product, I end up with [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4129139/sign-in-definition-of-cap-product) that was brillantly answered by Pedro Tamaroff. The only part which is not clear to me, as suggested in the answer, is why should we use the Koszul sign-rule when we want to transform $A \otimes B$ in $B\otimes A$, in particular $x \otimes y \to (-1)^{\lvert y \rvert \lvert x \rvert} y \otimes x$.

This argument is used to prove that $ \varphi \frown \sigma = (-1)^{\lvert \varphi \rvert \lvert \sigma \rvert} \sigma \frown \varphi$. So my question is why do we use Koszul-sign rule in the first place? A similar post was asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4129139/sign-in-definition-of-cap-product); Although my question in the specific is: if I don't use the exchange it seems that I end up with the same formula without the sign, so I don't understand why should I use it.

Some suggested that is a convention introduced by Koszul, but with the term "Koszul-sign rule" all but me seem to know what the precise definition is, so I'd like to ask you whether you could help me clarify this detail.

Any help or reference would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/359960)?

Comment: @ZhenLin I did, and the sentence I'm interested in is "Homology functor $H_*(,k)$ from topological spaces to graded vector spaces is symmetric monoidal, but only with respect to the Koszul sign rule." that I think answers my question. Are you able to explain this concept to me since I don't know  what a symmetric monoidal is (except for its definition)?

Comment: It means that $H_* (X \times Y, k) \cong H_* (X, k) \otimes_k H_* (Y, k)$ in a natural way (if you use the Koszul sign rule).

Comment: @ZhenLin The isomorphism I have in mind right now is related to Künneth Theorem, although my proof seems to be hide under the rug the Koszul-sign rule to prove it (if that's the case).

Comment: In brief, not it using it will create incorrect formulas, maps that are not chain maps, products that are not associative, etc. You'll get wrong results!

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Could you explain with just an example why?

Comment: @jacopoburelli Consider two complexes $(C,d)$ and $(D,d)$. Then $D(x\otimes y) = dx\otimes y  + x \otimes d'y$ is in general not differential on $C\otimes D$.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Thanks Pedro I noticed that, what worried me that I don't get is:  the exchange due to Koszul sign rule is not a real exchange (am I wrong?), but is up to isomorphism that $x \otimes y \to (-1)^{\lvert y\rvert \lvert x \rvert } y \otimes x$, so the exchange in the cap product doesn't look like an equality but an equality up to isomorphism. Where did I get it wrong?